# Limit of this sequence $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n + 3^n + 4^n}{5^n + 6^n}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to find the limit of this sequence. I tried using the squeeze theorem but no result yet.

$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n + 3^n + 4^n}{5^n + 6^n}}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to show your work on the problem, you'll get better feedback.

Comment: As a warm-up, try $\lim\sqrt[n]{2^n+1000^n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see that $$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{4^n}{6^n})<\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n}<3(\frac{4^n}{6^n}).$$ Therefore,
$$\frac{4}{6}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2}}<(\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n})^\frac{1}{n}<\sqrt[n]{3}\frac{4}{6}.$$ Since $\sqrt[n]{c}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, we have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n})^\frac{1}{n}=\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: Hi @alans, can you tell how you got this $$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{4^n}{6^n})<\frac{2^n+3^n+4^n}{5^n+6^n}<3(\frac{4^n}{6^n})$$

Comment: @ user215805 Factor 1/2 I got from two inequalities: $2^n+3^n+4^n>4^n$ and $2*6^n>5^n+6^n$, similarly I got other inequality: $2^n+3^n+4^n<3*4^n$ and $5^n+6^n>6^n$.

Comment: thanks for reply +1.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is $\frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$. Prove that this is so.

HINT: Check that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $n(\epsilon)$ such that for all $n>n(\epsilon)$, the denominator $2^n+3^n+4^n$ satisfies $$(1-\epsilon)4^n \le 2^n+3^n+4^n \le (1+\epsilon)4^n.$$ Likewise, there is an $n'(\epsilon)$ such that for all $n>n'(\epsilon)$, the numerator $5^n+6^n$ satisfies $$(1-\epsilon)6^n \le 5^n+6^n\le (1+\epsilon)6^n.$$

So for each $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $n > \max\{n(\epsilon), n'(\epsilon)\}$ the followign holds:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1-\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}}\sqrt[n]{\frac{4^n}{6^n}} \le \sqrt[n]{\frac{5^n+6^n}{2^n+3^n+4^n}} \le \sqrt[n]{\frac{1+\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}}\sqrt[n]{\frac{4^n}{6^n}}$$

Can you finish from here.

Comment: you forgot the double cash signs at the end

Comment: Good catch, thank you!